# Pandas: select row where one specific column stays constant

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that keeps track the `item_id` with its price over time period:

```
item_id | item_price | day
   1    |     10     | 09-02-2000 # DD-MM-YYYY format
   2    |     24     | 10-02-2000
   1    |     10     | 20-02-2000
...
```

As you can see, the price of the item `1` does not change over time. How do I select all of the items that the specific column `item_price` does not change over time? I tried `groupby()`, but it does not seem to work right.

EDIT: desired output is all the `item_id` that its price does not change over time. For example: `item_id_list = [1, ...]`. It can be a list or a DataFrame Series.

Comment: Can you add an expected output along with your sample data? Not sure I fully understand what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I added the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here it is little bro

```
df.groupby('item_id').item_price.nunique()
```

And you keep the ones with one unique price.